# Pixelwise OR two images with numpy

Tags: python, numpy, image-processing

I am using numpy to numerically manipulate image data. I have two black and white images which I would like to perform a logical OR on (i.e. if a pixel is white in either image, the corresponding pixel in the output image is also white). I have an inelegant solution that works, but I'm certain there must be a more efficient way to do this with numpy.

This just compares the images pixel by pixel (with an offset `x` and `y` to position the sub-image in the larger image):

```
def insert_subimage_or(img, subimage, x, y):
    for yy in range(subimage.shape[0]):
        for xx in range(subimage.shape[1]):
            if not img[y + yy, x + xx]:
                img[y + yy, x + xx] = subimage[yy, xx]
```

This takes these two images:

[image]

[image]

And creates this one:

[image]

I am thinking using one image to index the other somehow might work, but haven't been able to get anything like that to work. I really just want to avoid having to iterate through every pixel of the source image in the two for loops.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
def insert_subimage(img, subimage, x,y):
    h,w = subimage.shape[:2]

    # one should check if
    # y + h >= img.shape[0] or
    # x + w >= img.shape[1]
    img[y: y+h, x: x+w] = img[y: y+h, x: x+w] | subimage
```